# Why Springboot Webclient.get() is not mapping correctly Json to Java object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-webclient

[In here I am using bodytoFlux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUtri.png)

```
public Flux<User> getUsers() {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/api/users?page=1")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(User.class);

}
```

[In here there is the structure returned by the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsF22.png)

```
{
"page": 2,
"per_page": 6,
"total": 12,
"total_pages": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 7,
        "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Lawson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Lindsay",
        "last_name": "Ferguson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tobias",
        "last_name": "Funke",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Byron",
        "last_name": "Fields",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "George",
        "last_name": "Edwards",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Rachel",
        "last_name": "Howell",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
    }
],
"support": {
    "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
    "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
   }
}
```

I think there should be a method to get data array with the expected values to map correctly but I haven't found it, please some ideas, maybe using a mapper in the get I don't know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported out-of-the-box in Spring WebFlux, but you can plug in a custom `BodyExtractor` implementation that does this based on a Jackson JsonPointer to select the right bits of the document.

This is documented on [the dedicated issue in Spring Framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24951). Feel free to upvote the issue.

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing directly with the client:

```
Flux<User> users = webClient.get()
    .uri("/api/users?page=1")
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Response.class)
    .flatMapMany(response -> Flux.fromIterable(response.getData()));
```